# What is the destination (rebirth) of a person with Vibhava Tanha?

Tags: theravada

What is the destination (rebirth) of a person with Vibhava Tanha?

There are three kinds of Tanha. (Kama, Bhava, Vibhava)
some description of Vibhava Tanha:

> “And how do some slip right past? Some, feeling horrified, humiliated, & disgusted with that very becoming, relish non-becoming: ‘When this self, at the break-up of the body, after death, perishes & is destroyed, and does not exist after death, that is peaceful, that is exquisite, that is sufficiency!’ This is how some slip right past.
>
> [Itivuttaka 49](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/KN/Iti/iti49.html)

See also [What is Vibhava Tanha?](https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=33188) (on Dhamma Wheel).

Answer (score 1):

yes there is not much on Vibhava Tanha in the suttas. The term Vibhava Tanha always appear without any detail.https://suttacentral.net/define/vibhava
Perhaps the closest you get is the dimension of nothing or perception-nonperpcetion like here https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.106.than.html

today some people say that Vibhava Tanha was added because puthujjanas managed to think that a lack of bhava Tanha means idolizing suicide, so they countered that with the lack of the formal opposite of bhava tanha, which is Vibhava Tanha...

Comment: while this answer was astute to identify MN 106, i marked it down because it appears MN 106 does not refer to vibhava tanha. If this answer includes some relevant quotes, i might change my view of it.